# Import Excel file to Datagridview in C# or VB.Net

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, datagridview

hi i have excel file with following fields name,mobileNo,TotalCoupen.i want to import these field in datagridview with unique serial no.if a person have total 5 coupen it will show 5 coupen serial like (10001,10002,10003,10004,10005) i also attach image [image]

[image]

here is my code
this code load excel file successfuly but not generate coupen no it only import excel file

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.Data.OleDb;
 using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

 namespace ReadExcelFileApp
 {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Visible = false;
    }

    private void btnChoose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = string.Empty;
        string fileExt = string.Empty;
        OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();//open dialog to choose file
        if (file.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)//if there is a file choosen by the user
        {
            filePath = file.FileName;//get the path of the file
            fileExt = Path.GetExtension(filePath);//get the file extension
            if (fileExt.CompareTo(".xls") == 0 || fileExt.CompareTo(".xlsx") == 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();
                    dtExcel = ReadExcel(filePath, fileExt);//read excel file
                    dataGridView1.Visible = true;
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dtExcel;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please choose .xls or .xlsx file only.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);//custom messageBox to show error
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();//to close the window(Form1)
    }

    public DataTable ReadExcel(string fileName, string fileExt)
    {
        string conn = string.Empty;
        DataTable dtexcel = new DataTable();
        if (fileExt.CompareTo(".xls") == 0)//compare the extension of the file
            conn = @"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HRD=Yes;IMEX=1';";//for below excel 2007
        else
            conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';";//for above excel 2007
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conn))
        {
            try
            {
                OleDbDataAdapter oleAdpt = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", con);//here we read data from sheet1
                oleAdpt.Fill(dtexcel);//fill excel data into dataTable
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
        return dtexcel;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You will probably need to show what you have tried to attract an answer see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) see also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: do the column names in your grid match the excel fields?

Comment: ok but how i add coupen number in each row unique like above image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you would want to add these IMHO duplicate rows. A simple solution is to create a new `DataTable` with the extra rows. Loop through all the rows in the excel data table then loop `total coupen`  times for each new row then update `coupen no` as the picture shows. Again I am not sure why you would do this but here is one way. The code below makes a new `DataTable` from the `DataTable` returned from `ReadExcel` method. The `AddDuplicates` methods add the rows as per the requirement.

```
dtExcel = ReadExcel(filePath, fileExt);//read excel file
DataTable dgvTable = AddDuplicates(dtExcel);
dataGridView1.Visible = true;
//dataGridView1.DataSource = dtExcel;
dataGridView1.DataSource = dgvTable;

private DataTable AddDuplicates(DataTable dt) {
  DataTable dtcopy = dt.Clone();
  int curCount = 100000;
  double coupenCount = 0;
  foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
    coupenCount = (double)dr.ItemArray[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < coupenCount; i++) {
      dtcopy.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray[0], dr.ItemArray[1], ++curCount);
    }
  }
  return dtcopy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
            System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
            MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\csharp.net-informations.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
            MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection);
            MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com");
            DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
            MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
            MyConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```